# absolutely pure emacs initialization

Tags: emacs

I'd like to run emacs without any installed plugins. Emacs manual says that you may use `-q` option to skip init file. I've tried `emacs -q` and discovered that plugins from /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp (ubuntu installs plugins here) are still loaded.

I've searched google about emacs's initialization routine and found nothing usefull. I'm curios what emacs do step by step while initializing and what variables, options, evironment, etc. may change default behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `emacs -Q`

From the manpage:

> **-Q, --quick**
>      Similar to "-q --no-site-file --no-splash".  Also, avoid processing X resources.

---

If you only want to avoid loading site lisp code, you might want to run

`emacs -q --no-site-file`

Answer (score 3):

Emacs == self-documenting.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Emacs Invocation` <kbd>RET</kbd>

If you really want to get into the details, you can peruse startup.el with

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `startup` <kbd>RET</kbd>